# Trying to use google play services ad feature in unity3D i don't have any errors but i can't see my ads

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, google-play-services

I'm trying to add google-play-services's "com.google.androind.gms.ads" to my unity project to load ads i feel like i have come quite far as i no longer have any errors from calling the java classes. However i am now kind of stuck as i have no errors and no ads.

Here´s the code in my unity c# class.

```
    Debug.Log("Instantiate STARTED");
    unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    currActivityUnity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    admobPluginClassAdSize = new AndroidJavaClass("com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize");
    AndroidJavaObject adSize = admobPluginClassAdSize.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("FULL_BANNER");
    admobPluginClassAdView = new AndroidJavaObject("com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView",
    currActivityUnity);
    admobPluginClassAdListener = new AndroidJavaClass("com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener");
    admobPluginClassAdRequestBuilder = new AndroidJavaObject("com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest$Builder");
    admobPluginClassAdView.Call("setAdSize", adSize);
    admobPluginClassAdView.Call("setAdUnitId", pubID);
    admobPluginClassAdRequestBuilder = admobPluginClassAdRequestBuilder.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("addTestDevice", testDeviceId);
    admobPluginClassAdRequest = admobPluginClassAdRequestBuilder.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("build");
    currActivityUnity.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(() =>
        {
            admobPluginClassAdView.Call("loadAd", admobPluginClassAdRequest);
        }));
    Debug.Log("Instantiate FINISHED");
```

My com.google.androind.gms AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.gms"
    android:versionCode="4323030"
    android:versionName="4.3.23 (1069729-030)" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"/>
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
               android:debuggable="true">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="BannerExample">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```

My com.unity3d.player AndroidManifest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
                  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.VideoPlayer"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are doing way more than you need to.  Have you checked out Google's latest Admob Unity3D release?

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-plugins

Using the README in their repository you should be able to load / show ads without touching any Java classes.  The sample they provide has all the code you need.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Here's my Unity Side code

```
public static void Init()
{
    AndroidJavaClass playerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject activity = playerClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.google.android.gms.samples.ads.GoogleAdsSampleActivity");
    pluginClass.CallStatic("Init",
                           new object[1] {activity});
}

// Show the banner view on the screen.
public static void ShowBannerAds() {
    Debug.Log ("AdmobPlugin ShowBannerAds ");
    AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.google.android.gms.samples.ads.GoogleAdsSampleActivity");
    pluginClass.CallStatic("ShowBannerAds");
}

// Hide the banner view from the screen.
public static void HideBannerView()
{
    AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.google.android.gms.samples.ads.GoogleAdsSampleActivity");
    pluginClass.CallStatic("hideBannerView");
}
```

And Java Plugin which you create a jar and keep it in Plugins/Android folder

```
 public class GoogleAdsSampleActivity {
private static GoogleAdsSampleActivity instance;
private Activity activity;
private AdView adView;
public static GoogleAdsSampleActivity instance()
{
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new GoogleAdsSampleActivity();
    }
    return instance;
}


public static void Init(final Activity activity)
{
    final GoogleAdsSampleActivity plugin = instance();
    plugin.activity = activity;
    plugin.activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() {
          //Intent main= new Intent(plugin.activity, BannerCodeActivity.class);

          Log.d("GoogleAdsSampleActivity stat11 = ", status);

          plugin.adView = new AdView(plugin.activity);
          plugin.adView.setAdUnitId("XYZ");  // Your Admob key
          plugin.adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

          LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(plugin.activity);
          FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            -1, -2);
          layoutParams.gravity = (false ? 48 : 80);
          plugin.activity.addContentView(layout, layoutParams);
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            -1, -1);
          layout.addView(plugin.adView, adParams);
          plugin.adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    });
}
public static void ShowBannerAds () {
    final GoogleAdsSampleActivity plugin = instance();
    plugin.activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() {
          plugin.adView.setVisibility(0);

        }
    });

}
public static void hideBannerView () {
    final GoogleAdsSampleActivity plugin = instance();
    plugin.activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() {
            plugin.adView.setVisibility(8);

        }
    });
}
```

}